# googleads api report cost incorrect - How get the correct cost value? - Python

Tags: python-3.x, google-api-python-client

When I use the python: googleads-python-lib.
All is working good, but when I get the cost value from a campaing the value is incorrect.

Imagine that the cost has this value: $44,396.12
Then in the response of the code XML the cost value is: 44396120000

```
report_downloader = adwords_client.GetReportDownloader(version='v201705')
report = { 'reportName': 'Last 7 days CRITERIA_PERFORMANCE_REPORT', 'dateRangeType': 'ALL_TIME', 'reportType': 'ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT', 'downloadFormat': 'XML', 'selector': { 'fields': ['Impressions', 'Clicks', 'Cost', 'AverageCost', 'ActiveViewMeasurableCost'] } }
xml=report_downloader.DownloadReportAsString( report, skip_report_header=True, skip_column_header=False, skip_report_summary=True, include_zero_impressions=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
'${:,.2f}'.format(44396120000/1000000)
```

That'll format the number if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Your solutions es good, but imagine the cost value is: $55.55 (5555) or imagine: $1254.45 ( 125445)

Comment: I did do something like this:

Comment: val = '45672890000'
end='end'
val=val+end
print(val)
result=val.split('0000end')
result= result[0]

print(result)

print ('${:,.2f}'.format(int(result)/100))

Comment: Google cost always put '0000' in the end of the string.